# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined" in jqcloud

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using [jqcloud](http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/demo.html) directive. I followed all the steps described in the document. but still it does not work.

My code:

HTML

```
<div class="item" href="/clients"></div>

  <ion-content ng-controller="clientsController as clients" style="margin-top: 25px">

<div class="demo">

  <jqcloud words="clients.words" width="500" height="350" steps="7"></jqcloud>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    angular.module('starter.clientsController', ['ionic', 'angular-jqcloud'])
.controller('clientsController', function ($scope){

$scope.words = [{text: "Lorem", weight: 13},
  {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5},
  {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4},
  {text: "Sit", weight: 8},
  {text: "Amet", weight: 6.2},
  {text: "Consectetur", weight: 5},
  {text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5},];

});
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was that I did not add the `jqcloud.js` file, i only added the wrapper.
Now, I don't get the error, but I get a blank page.

Comment: Do you need `$('#demo').jQCloud(words);`? That doesn't seem the angular way of doing things. (no dom manipulation in your controller). The docs you linked appears to be the plain jQuery stuff. Yet your using a directive for this. So i presume you have another library which wraps the jQuery stuff in a directive which is the angular way of doing this. So from that i believe the directive is doing that jQuery call for you.

Comment: you are right I already deleted it. I ll update my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have used #demo id but never used in HTML code:
Try the following:

```
  <div class="item" href="/clients"></div>
  <ion-content ng-controller="clientsController" style="margin-top: 25px">
      <div id='demo' width="500" height="350" steps="7"></div>
  </ion-content>
```

Angular part:

```
angular.module('starter.clientsController', ['ionic', 'angular-jqcloud'])
.controller('clientsController', function ($scope){

$scope.words = [{text: "Lorem", weight: 13},
  {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5},
  {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4},
  {text: "Sit", weight: 8},
  {text: "Amet", weight: 6.2},
  {text: "Consectetur", weight: 5},
  {text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5},];

$('#demo').jQCloud($scope.words);
});
```

Comment: still getting this error: ReferenceError: words is not defined